# A conjecture relate to Euler's sum of powers conjecture

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, conjectures, perfect-powers

I am ZHICHEN LIU(Will). I made a conjecture based on Euler's sum of powers conjecture. I think it works, but I don't know if anyone made this conjecture before. So I hope anyone can give me some directions, or give to me one counterexample to this conjecture I made.

Euler's conjecture:
Assume $X_1$, $X_2$,$X_3$, ... , $X_n$ are integers, and m is positive whole number.

$X_1^m+X_2^m+X_3^m+...+X_n^m=Y^m$                             (1)

If equation (1) holds, then Y won't have integer solution if m is greater than n.

My conjecture (My apologize if someone did this before.):

Assume $X_1$, $X_2$,$X_3$, ... , $X_n$ are integers, additionally,  $X_1$, $X_2$,$X_3$, ... , $X_n$ are relatively prime pairs , and m is positive whole number.

$X_1^m+X_2^m+X_3^m+...+X_n^m=Y^m$                             (2)

then If equation (2) holds, then Y won't have integer solution if m is greater than n.

(Basically, I think the Euler's sum of powers conjecture need $X_1$, $X_2$,$X_3$, ... , $X_n$ to be relatively prime pairs)

For example:

$X_1$, $X_2$,$X_3$ are integers,

Additionally, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are relatively primes, $X_1$ and $X_3$ are relatively primes, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are relatively primes.

$X_1^3+X_2^3+X_3^3=Y^3$                                               (3)

then if equation (3) holds, then Y won't have integer solution.

Comment: It sounds like you are making the conjecture weaker (i.e., original conjecture $\implies$ your conjecture).  This might be motivated if you have reason to believe the stronger conjecture is false.  Note that if there is an integer solution to (1), then we can always remove any factors that all the $X_i$ numbers have in common.  Why do you go further and require all pairs to be relatively prime?

Comment: Euler's conjecture is known false for $m=4$ and $m=5$. One of those known counterexamples also disproves Will's conjecture.

Comment: You are right, 55^5+3183^5+28969^5+85282^5=85359^5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$55^5 + 3183^5 + 28969^5 + 85282^5 = 85359^5$$

Comment: yes, I realized, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See https://sites.google.com/site/sevensixthpowers/ for (6,1,7) solutions, showing examples where many $X_i$ must share one or more common factors, due to modular constrains (mod 7, 8 and 9 in this case).